# How to reduce jpg size saved from a base64 string C#

Tags: c#, image, base64

I'm receiving a base64 string from the client side that represents a jpg and I'm saving it using the following code

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64File.base64Data);                
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
                {
                    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);                    
                    image.Save("aPath");                    
                }
```

The problem is that that the original image entered on the client side (before the base64 encoding) is about 3MB and once that I save it using the method above, it turns to be a 24MB image!

Is there any way to reduce it's size? (I know that sending big images encoded in base64 is not very smart, but I need to find a solution keeping this part)

Comment: Why are you converting it to an `Image` first? If it's a JPEG just save `imageBytes` directly.

Comment: You want to reduce it's size on disk? Did you try saving it to a different format, like PNG? : `image.Save("apath", ImageFormat.Png);`

Comment: And how big is base64 string itself?

Comment: "image.Save(path)", without save type parameter, _always produces png._

Answer (score 3):

Just save the bytes, don't convert it back into an image, otherwise you will have to use the same settings as when it was originally saved.

I.e its already the image you want, loading it from a stream and calling save, saves it as a bitmap in probably 32bit

**Update**

> So I tried the code below
>
> `byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64File.base64Data);` `File.WriteAllBytes("apath"),imageBytes);`
>
> But it generates a 18MB file,
>   still much larger than the original

Basically this means, when ever you are converting it base64 (server side), it is probably doing the same thing. Maybe its loading it into an `Image` and saving the bytes before converting it to Base64.

I believe a way to tell if the image is actually a bitmap (in your case) before  conversion base64, is just look to see if the first 2 bytes of the file are BM.

Either way, the image is being manipulated on the other side before its converted to base64, maybe its a bitmap or its just reenconding it, its hard to tell. That's to say base64 encoding isn't smart enough to reenconde the image format and inflate the size

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I tried the code below

`byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64File.base64Data);
                File.WriteAllBytes("apath"),imageBytes);`

But it generates a 18MB file, still much larger than the original. Do you have any other idea?